# Google Apps Script Trim White Space at the beginning of a string for an entire column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split, substring, trim

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uO6mw6T9vK9mN8ZRtCJXX5UT8yV_rL-4_fD2TZbiDbk/edit#gid=1804681073) Tab - **Result**

I want to remove spaces in front of the text in Col. B

None of the codes I tried seem to be working. I tried the replace method, then split & join. But it still leaves a blank space in front of the text.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Result";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  sheet.getRange('B2:B').activate();
  var ranges = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    ranges[i].getValue().split(' ').join('');
```

I did numerous searches in stack and Google, but none of them seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart

Comment: I already saw that page Cooper. But I don't know how to apply it to a single column. Sorry I'm a novice to scripts.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see data in Tab 'Result' - Column B to test it out but if you're just trying to remove blank space from the beginning of the text in a range, you can try:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Result";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastRow);
  range.trimWhitespace();
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `replaceAll(" ","")` to your string:

```
ranges[i].getValue().replaceAll(" ","")
```